# RestKit: how to make a mapping for varying key names

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I'm trying to make a dynamic mapping for a bit weird structured JSON.
I have "array mapped to object" sort of thins so that array indices
ake keys e.g.:

```
{
 "0": {object},
 "1": {another object},
 "2": {yet another object},
 ...
}
```

All objects are of the same type so they can be parsed using the same
mapping, but how to deal with varying key names?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the section on "Handling Dynamic Nesting Attributes" in the [Object Mapping docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping).

He walks through an example (copied here) with the JSON:

```
{ "blake": {
    "email": "blake@restkit.org",
    "favorite_animal": "Monkey"
    }
}
```

Corresponding to the User class:

```
@interface User : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* email
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* favoriteAnimal;
@end
```

Which, you'll notice, the username property corresponds to the **key** of the JSON.

In order to map it, he uses a special parenthesis syntax to indicate that they key itself is a property:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class] ];
[mapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"username"];
[mapping mapFromKeyPath:@"(username).email" toAttribute:"email"];
[mapping mapFromKeyPath:@"(username).favorite_animal" toAttribute:"favoriteAnimal"];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: restKit now updated, you should use [`addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute`](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes)