# RestKit mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute with array

Tags: json, restkit

I have a JSON response which looks like the sample below. I have added some comments `//` to emphasize my question.

I have no idea how to build the `RKObjectMapping` for the dynamic keys ("FieldNameA", "FieldNameB" - this could be anything) in combination with the array as the value. Each item of the array is of a type `FieldResult`.

I already learned how to handle varying key names [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056807/restkit-how-to-make-a-mapping-for-varying-key-names), but I don't get how I could properly map the array item type.

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": "FAILURE",
        "details": {
            "FieldNameA": [ // dynamic key name here, array of objects as a value
                {
                    "details": {
                        "errorName": "InvalidField",
                        "errorNumber": 123
                        },
                    "status": "FAILURE"
                }
            ],
            "FieldNameB": [ // multiple values in this array, all of same type FieldResult
                {
                    "details": {
                        "errorName": "UpdateRequired",
                        "errorNumber": 321
                        },
                    "status": "UPDATE_REQUIRED",
                    "suggestion": {
                        "update": "UpdatedInputValue"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "details": {
                        "errorName": "TooShort",
                        "errorNumber": 1
                    },
                    "status": "FAILURE"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the wiki at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping with the section "Dynamic Object Mapping"?